# C++, combining two projects

Tags: c++

Im total beginner. I have a C++ GUI project in Visual Studio. It's working fine.

I would like to launch a function (when pressing a button in GUI) from existing cpp file opencvtesti.cpp, which I'm trying to include into this GUI project.

I added a existing file by pressing right mouse button over "source files" and added "opencvtesti.cpp". This .cpp was also workign fine before combining it to this GUI project. Also created opencvtesti.h and removed #includes from .cpp.

My code looks like this. But something goes wrong. Is there some dublicates in variables? I can't find them... I think I have done something wrong.

Errors:

```
Error   LNK1169 one or more multiply defined symbols found  Project5    C:\Users\....Project5.exe   1   
Error   LNK2005 "class Pylon::CPylonImage __cdecl SampleImageCreator::CreateMandelbrotFractal(enum Pylon::EPixelType,unsigned int,unsigned int)" (?CreateMandelbrotFractal@SampleImageCreator@@$$FYA?AVCPylonImage@Pylon@@W4EPixelType@3@II@Z) already defined in MyForm.obj    Project5    C:\Users\....\source\repos\Project5\Project5\opencvtesti.obj    1   
Error   LNK2005 "class Pylon::CPylonImage __cdecl SampleImageCreator::CreateJuliaFractal(enum Pylon::EPixelType,unsigned int,unsigned int)" (?CreateJuliaFractal@SampleImageCreator@@$$FYA?AVCPylonImage@Pylon@@W4EPixelType@3@II@Z) already defined in MyForm.obj  Project5    C:\Users\....\source\repos\Project5\Project5\opencvtesti.obj    1   
Error   LNK2005 "class Pylon::CPylonImage __cdecl SampleImageCreator::CreateMandelbrotFractal(enum Pylon::EPixelType,unsigned int,unsigned int)" (?CreateMandelbrotFractal@SampleImageCreator@@YA?AVCPylonImage@Pylon@@W4EPixelType@3@II@Z) already defined in MyForm.obj   Project5    C:\Users\...\source\repos\Project5\Project5\opencvtesti.obj 1   
Error   LNK2005 "class Pylon::CPylonImage __cdecl SampleImageCreator::CreateJuliaFractal(enum Pylon::EPixelType,unsigned int,unsigned int)" (?CreateJuliaFractal@SampleImageCreator@@YA?AVCPylonImage@Pylon@@W4EPixelType@3@II@Z) already defined in MyForm.obj Project5    C:\Users\...\source\repos\Project5\Project5\opencvtesti.obj 1
```

MyForm.cpp:

```
#include "MyForm.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
[STAThreadAttribute]

void main(array<String^>^ args) {
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Project5::MyForm form;
    Application::Run(% form);

}
```

MyForm.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include "Python.h"
#include "opencvtesti.h"

namespace Project5 {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary for MyForm
    /// </summary>
    public ref class MyForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        MyForm(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: Add the constructor code here
            //
        }

    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        ~MyForm()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }

    protected:

    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^ button1;

    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            this->button1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this->button1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(13, 67);
            this->button1->Name = L"button1";
            this->button1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 23);
            this->button1->TabIndex = 2;
            this->button1->Text = L"Press this";
            this->button1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->button1->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::button1_Click);
            // 
            // MyForm
            // 
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(187, 180);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button1);
            this->Name = L"MyForm";
            this->Text = L"GUI test";
            this->ResumeLayout(false);

        }
#pragma endregion

private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
    std::ofstream outfile("aukeaako.txt");
    outfile << "No aukeniko? :)" << std::endl;
        outfile.close();

    Py_Initialize();
    FILE* fd = fopen("aukesko.py", "r");
    PyRun_SimpleFileEx(fd, "aukesko.py", 0);
}
};
}
```

opencvtesti.h:

```
#ifndef OPENCVTESTI_H
#define OPENCVTESTI_H

#pragma once
#include <pylon/PylonIncludes.h>
#include <pylon/PylonGUI.h>
#include <SampleImageCreator.h>
#include <conio.h>

int opencvtesti();

#endif
```

opencvtesti.cpp:

```
#include "opencvtesti.h"

// Namespace for using pylon objects.
using namespace Pylon;

// Namespace for using cout.
using namespace std;

// Number of images to be grabbed.
static const uint32_t c_countOfImagesToGrab = 1000;

int opencvtesti(int /*argc*/, char* /*argv*/[])
{
    // The exit code of the sample application.
    int exitCode = 0;

    // Before using any pylon methods, the pylon runtime must be initialized.
    PylonInitialize();

    try
    {
        // Define constants.
        static const uint32_t cNumTilesX = 3;
        static const uint32_t cNumTilesY = 2;
        static const uint32_t cWindowBorderSizeX = 25;
        static const uint32_t cWindowBorderSizeY = 125;
        static const uint32_t cScreenStartX = 40;
        static const uint32_t cScreenStartY = 40;
        static const uint32_t cMaxIndex = 31;
        static const size_t   cNumWindows = cNumTilesY * cNumTilesX;
        static const uint32_t cMaxWidth = 640;
        static const uint32_t cMaxHeight = 480;

        // Create an array of image windows.
        CPylonImageWindow imageWindows[cNumWindows];

        // Create an Instant Camera object.
        CInstantCamera camera(CTlFactory::GetInstance().CreateFirstDevice());

        // Print the model name of the camera.
        cout << "Using device " << camera.GetDeviceInfo().GetModelName() << endl;

        // Start the grab. Only display the latest image.
        camera.StartGrabbing(c_countOfImagesToGrab, GrabStrategy_LatestImageOnly);

        // This smart pointer will receive the grab result data.
        CGrabResultPtr ptrGrabResult;

        // Grab images and show the tiles of each image in separate image windows.
        while (camera.IsGrabbing())
        {
            // Wait for an image and then retrieve it. A timeout of 5000 ms is used.
            camera.RetrieveResult(5000, ptrGrabResult, TimeoutHandling_ThrowException);

            // If the image was grabbed successfully.
            if (ptrGrabResult->GrabSucceeded())
            {
                // This image object is used for splitting the grabbed image into tiles.
                CPylonImage image;

                // Attach the grab result to a pylon image.
                image.AttachGrabResultBuffer(ptrGrabResult);

                // Compute tile sizes.
                uint32_t imageTileWidth = min(image.GetWidth(), cMaxWidth) / cNumTilesX;
                uint32_t imageTileHeight = min(image.GetHeight(), cMaxHeight) / cNumTilesY;
                imageTileWidth -= imageTileWidth % GetPixelIncrementX(image.GetPixelType());
                imageTileHeight -= imageTileWidth % GetPixelIncrementY(image.GetPixelType());

                uint32_t windowTileWidth = imageTileWidth + cWindowBorderSizeX;
                uint32_t windowTileHeight = imageTileHeight + cWindowBorderSizeY;

                // Create and display the tiles of the grabbed image.
                for (uint32_t indexTileX = 0; indexTileX < cNumTilesX; ++indexTileX)
                {
                    for (uint32_t indexTileY = 0; indexTileY < cNumTilesY; ++indexTileY)
                    {
                        size_t arrayIndex = indexTileY * cNumTilesX + indexTileX;
                        bool windowCreated = false;

                        if (!imageWindows[arrayIndex].IsValid())
                        {
                            // Create the image window and position the image window as a tile on the screen.
                            // The Image Window stores the last size and position.
                            // The last Image Window indices are used here to avoid changing
                            // the settings of the windows used for other samples.
                            size_t windowIndex = cMaxIndex - arrayIndex;
                            imageWindows[arrayIndex].Create(windowIndex,
                                cScreenStartX + indexTileX * windowTileWidth,
                                cScreenStartY + indexTileY * windowTileHeight,
                                windowTileWidth,
                                windowTileHeight
                            );

                            windowCreated = true;
                        }

                        // Get the image area of interest (Image AOI) that includes the tile. This is a zero copy operation.
                        CPylonImage tile = image.GetAoi(indexTileX * imageTileWidth, indexTileY * imageTileHeight, imageTileWidth, imageTileHeight);

                        // Set the tile image.
                        imageWindows[arrayIndex].SetImage(tile);

                        // Show the image.
                        imageWindows[arrayIndex].Show();

                        if (windowCreated)
                        {
                            // Wait a little to show how the windows appear on the screen.
                            ::Sleep(200);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw RUNTIME_EXCEPTION("Error image grab failed: %hs", ptrGrabResult->GetErrorDescription().c_str());
            }
        }

        // Destroy the windows.
        for (size_t arrayIndex = 0; arrayIndex < cNumWindows; ++arrayIndex)
        {
            // Close() closes and destroys the window.
            imageWindows[arrayIndex].Close();

            // Wait a little to show how the windows are removed from the screen.
            ::Sleep(200);
        }
    }
    catch (const GenericException& e)
    {
        // Error handling.
        cerr << "An exception occurred." << endl
            << e.GetDescription() << endl;
        exitCode = 1;

        cerr << endl << "Press enter to exit." << endl;
        while (cin.get() != '\n');
    }

    // Releases all pylon resources.
    PylonTerminate();

    return exitCode;
}
```

Edit:
SampelImageCreator.h looks like this:

```
// Contains functions for creating sample images.

#ifndef INCLUDED_SAMPLEIMAGECREATOR_H_2792867
#define INCLUDED_SAMPLEIMAGECREATOR_H_2792867

#include <pylon/PylonImage.h>
#include <pylon/Pixel.h>
#include <pylon/ImageFormatConverter.h>

namespace SampleImageCreator
{
    Pylon::CPylonImage CreateJuliaFractal( Pylon::EPixelType pixelType, uint32_t width, uint32_t height )
    {
        // Allow all the names in the namespace Pylon to be used without qualification.
        using namespace Pylon;

        // Define Constants.
        static const SRGB8Pixel palette[] =
        {
            {0, 28, 50}, {0, 42, 75}, {0, 56, 100}, {0, 70, 125}, {0, 84, 150},
            {0, 50, 0}, {0, 100, 0}, {0, 150, 0}, {0, 200, 0}, {0, 250, 0},
            {50, 0, 0}, {100, 0, 0}, {150, 0, 0}, {200, 0, 0}, {250, 0, 0}
        };
        uint32_t numColors = sizeof( palette ) / sizeof( palette[0] );

        const double cX = -0.735;
        const double cY = 0.11;
        const double cMaxX = 1.6;
        const double cMinX = -1.6;
        const double cMaxY = 1;
        const double cMinY = -1;
        const uint32_t cMaxIterations = 50;

        // Create image.
        CPylonImage juliaFractal( CPylonImage::Create( PixelType_RGB8packed, width, height ) );

        // Get the pointer to the first pixel.
        SRGB8Pixel* pCurrentPixel = (SRGB8Pixel*) juliaFractal.GetBuffer();

        // Compute the fractal.
        for (uint32_t pixelY = 0; pixelY < height; ++pixelY)
        {
            for (uint32_t pixelX = 0; pixelX < width; ++pixelX, ++pCurrentPixel)
            {
                long double x = ((cMaxX - cMinX) / width) * pixelX + cMinX;
                long double y = cMaxY - pixelY * ((cMaxY - cMinY) / height);
                long double xd = 0;
                long double yd = 0;
                uint32_t i = 0;

                for (; i < cMaxIterations; ++i)
                {
                    xd = x * x - y * y + cX;
                    yd = 2 * x * y + cY;
                    x = xd;
                    y = yd;
                    if ((x * x + y * y) > 4)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (i >= cMaxIterations)
                {
                    *pCurrentPixel = palette[0];
                }
                else
                {
                    *pCurrentPixel = palette[i % numColors];
                }
            }
        }

        // Convert the image to the target format if needed.
        if (juliaFractal.GetPixelType() != pixelType)
        {
            CImageFormatConverter converter;
            converter.OutputPixelFormat = pixelType;
            converter.OutputBitAlignment = OutputBitAlignment_MsbAligned;
            converter.Convert( juliaFractal, CPylonImage( juliaFractal ) );
        }

        // Return the image.
        return juliaFractal;
    }


    Pylon::CPylonImage CreateMandelbrotFractal( Pylon::EPixelType pixelType, uint32_t width, uint32_t height )
    {
        // Allow all the names in the namespace Pylon to be used without qualification.
        using namespace Pylon;

        // Define constants.
        static const SRGB8Pixel palette[] =
        {
            {0, 28, 50}, {0, 42, 75}, {0, 56, 100}, {0, 70, 125}, {0, 84, 150},
            {0, 50, 0}, {0, 100, 0}, {0, 150, 0}, {0, 200, 0}, {0, 250, 0},
            {50, 0, 0}, {100, 0, 0}, {150, 0, 0}, {200, 0, 0}, {250, 0, 0}
        };
        uint32_t numColors = sizeof( palette ) / sizeof( palette[0] );

        const double  cMaxX = 1.0;
        const double  cMinX = -2.0;
        const double  cMaxY = 1.2;
        const double  cMinY = -1.2;
        const uint32_t cMaxIterations = 50;

        // Create image.
        CPylonImage mandelbrotFractal( CPylonImage::Create( PixelType_RGB8packed, width, height ) );

        // Get the pointer to the first pixel.
        SRGB8Pixel* pCurrentPixel = (SRGB8Pixel*) mandelbrotFractal.GetBuffer();

        // Compute the fractal.
        for (uint32_t pixelY = 0; pixelY < height; ++pixelY)
        {
            for (uint32_t pixelX = 0; pixelX < width; ++pixelX, ++pCurrentPixel)
            {
                long double xStart = ((cMaxX - cMinX) / width) * pixelX + cMinX;
                long double yStart = cMaxY - pixelY * ((cMaxY - cMinY) / height);
                long double x = xStart;
                long double y = yStart;
                long double xd = 0;
                long double yd = 0;
                uint32_t i = 0;

                for (; i < cMaxIterations; ++i)
                {
                    xd = x * x - y * y + xStart;
                    yd = 2 * x * y + yStart;
                    x = xd;
                    y = yd;
                    if ((x * x + y * y) > 4)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (i >= cMaxIterations)
                {
                    *pCurrentPixel = palette[0];
                }
                else
                {
                    *pCurrentPixel = palette[i % numColors];
                }
            }
        }

        // Convert the image to the target format if needed.
        if (mandelbrotFractal.GetPixelType() != pixelType)
        {
            CImageFormatConverter converter;
            converter.OutputPixelFormat = pixelType;
            converter.OutputBitAlignment = OutputBitAlignment_MsbAligned;
            converter.Convert( mandelbrotFractal, CPylonImage( mandelbrotFractal ) );
        }

        // Return the image.
        return mandelbrotFractal;
    }

}

#endif /* INCLUDED_SAMPLEIMAGECREATOR_H_2792867 */
```

Comment: My guess, there are definitions in `SampleImageCreator.h` that are not inlined. Look at the definition of `CreateMandelbrotFractal`.

Comment: how are you linking to whatver the "Pylon" library is? Or are you including all of its source code into your project?

Comment: Added SampleImageCreator.h to original guestion. What would be the easiest fix?  I will also take some images from project properties to clarify library includings.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example you should read the section about "minimal"

Answer (score 1):

If you provide a definition of your function within a header file, you must declare it with `inline` keyword:

```
namespace SampleImageCreator
{
    inline Pylon::CPylonImage CreateJuliaFractal( Pylon::EPixelType pixelType, uint32_t width, uint32_t height )
    {
```

Also, Template functions are `inline` by default.
In your case you have an ODR (One Definition Rule) violation, that is your in-header defined functions are added to **every** translation unit that includes your header.  Multiple Definitions are not allowed, otherwise the linker would not know which definition to use.
But if you use `inline`, you allow the linker to have multiple definitions.

Comment: Thank you so much! It seems to build now. Have to study more of that inline. And sorry for that this wasn't a minimal question, I will try better next time.

Comment: @PMJ you should study about the process of compiling and linking, especially about ODR. Moreover, I would suggest you to learn how to use CMake instead of setting up your project in Visual Studio. That will help you to understand more on the matter.

Answer (score -2):

1. Try to wrap code in `opencvtesti` files in personal namespace to avoid problems with linking
2. Check all your headers, especially `SampleImageCreator.h` and make sure that there is no redefinition of the variables specified in the errors
3. It could be problem with call conventions, like `cdecl`. Chance is
   0.01%, but you can "play" with settings in `Properties -> C/C++ -> Other -> Call conventions`

[image: MVS Interface]

Comment: Thank you for your help. 1. Can you give some example how to wrap code in personal namespace?   2. I added the SampleImageCreator.h to original question. I cant find redefinitions, maybe?  3. Calling convention was empty, but __cdecl (/Gd) didn't change anything....

Comment: the error message has nothing to do with the calling convention. Also `multiple definitions` is a linker error, not a compiler error.

Comment: @PMJ You can see, how to use namespaces in the good answer of Sergei Kolesnik above :)